# OpenGL: Shader storage buffer mapping/binding

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently working on a program which supports **depth-independent** (also known as **order-independent**) **alpha blending**. To do that, I implemented a **per-pixel linked list**, using a texture for the header (points for every pixel to the first entry in the linked list) and a texture buffer object for the linked list itself. While this works fine, I would like to *exchange the texture buffer object with a shader storage buffer* as an excercise.

I think I almost got it, but it took me about a week to get to a point where I could actually use the shader storage buffer. My question are:

- Why I can't map the shader storage buffer?
- Why is it a problem to bind the shader storage buffer again?

For debugging, I just display the contents of the shader storage buffer (which doesn't contain a linked list yet). I created the shader storage buffer in the following way:

```
glm::vec4* bufferData = new glm::vec4[windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height];
glm::vec4* readBufferData = new glm::vec4[windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height];

for(unsigned int y = 0; y < windowOptions.height; ++y)
{
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < windowOptions.width; ++x)
    {
        // Set the whole buffer to red
        bufferData[x + y * windowOptions.width] = glm::vec4(1,0,0,1);
    }
}

GLuint ssb;
// Get a handle
glGenBuffers(1, &ssb);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssb);
// Create buffer
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height * sizeof(glm::vec4), bufferData, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
// Now bind the buffer to the shader
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssb);
```

In the shader, the shader storage buffer is defined as:

```
layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer BufferObject
{
    vec4 points[];
};
```

In the rendering loop, I do the following:

```
glUseProgram(defaultProgram);

for(unsigned int y = 0; y < windowOptions.height; ++y)
{
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < windowOptions.width; ++x)
    {
        // Create a green/red color gradient
        bufferData[x + y * windowOptions.width] =
            glm::vec4((float)x / (float)windowOptions.width,
            (float)y / (float)windowOptions.height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}

glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);  // Don't know if this is necessary, just a precaution
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height * sizeof(glm::vec4), bufferData);
// Retrieving the buffer also works fine
// glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
// glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height * sizeof(glm::vec4), readBufferData);

glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);  // Don't know if this is necessary, just a precaution

// Draw a quad which fills the screen
// ...
```

This code works, but when I replace **glBufferSubData** with the following code,

```
glm::vec4* p = (glm::vec4*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
for(unsigned int x = 0; x < windowOptions.width; ++x)
{
    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < windowOptions.height; ++y)
    {
        p[x + y * windowOptions.width] = glm::vec4(0,1,0,1);
    }
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
```

the mapping fails, returning **GL_INVALID_OPERATION**. It seems like the shader storage buffer is still bound to something, so it can't be mapped. I read something about **glGetProgramResourceIndex** (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGetProgramResourceIndex) and **glShaderStorageBlockBinding** (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlShaderStorageBlockBinding), but I don't really get it.

My second question is, why I can neither call

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssb);
```

, nor

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssb);
```

in the render loop after **glBufferSubData** and **glMemoryBarrier**. This code should not change a thing, since these calls are the same as during the creation of the shader storage buffer. If I can't bind different shader storage buffers, I can only use one. But I know that more than one shader storage buffer is supported, so I think I'm missing something else (like "releasing" the buffer).

Comment: *"My second question is, why I can neither call...in the render loop after..."* - In which way *"can't"* you call those functions? You can always call them, rather tell us what happens if you do.

Comment: When I call them (and check for errors) after I write to the buffer (and wait for glMemoryBarrier), glGetError() returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION. This only happens when I write to the buffer, not when reading from it.

Comment: That's not quite right. Both calls go through without error, but in the next frame, glBufferSubData or glMapBufferRange both fail with GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

Comment: Now that you have it working, does the SSBO make any difference compared to the texture buffer apart from syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `glMapBufferRange` fails simply because `GL_WRITE_ONLY` is not a valid argument to it. That was used for the old [`glMapBuffer`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml), but [`glMapBufferRange`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glMapBufferRange.xml) uses a collection of flags for more fine-grained control. In your case you need `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` instead. And since you seem to completely overwrite the whole buffer, without caring for the previous values, an additional optimization would probably be `GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT`. So replace that call with:

```
glm::vec4* p = (glm::vec4*)glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 
                    windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height, 
                    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The other error is not described that well in the question. But fix this one first and maybe it will already help with the following error.

Comment: It's almost right. I first got segfaults, but the I realized that the length argument was wrong, it has to be "windowOptions.width * windowOptions.height * sizeof(glm::vec4)", since it's not the number of elements, but the length in bytes. Now it works nicely. Thanks! But I still don't get why I can't call either glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, ssb) nor
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssb) after I write to the buffer. To be more precise, the call itself is alright, but in the next frame, the mapping fails.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I had a local variable of the same name inside the main function and a global variable. I created the buffer using the local variable, and tried to set the the active buffer to the global variable, which, of course, was not a valid buffer. Now everything works fine, thanks again!